Disable auto-suggestion
I would like to disable the WordPress auto-suggestions as they are seldom helpful and sometimes completely obstructive.
I tried adding to my functions.php the second code block from this other post (but to no avail): Can I disable the auto complete?


These aren't coming from WordPress, they're either from the plugin you're using or your browser. You'll need to ask the plugin developer for assistance with this issue.

@JacobPeattie, no they are not styled as per the browser. These are WP suggestions.

WordPress doesn't add anything like this, if it's not from the browser then it's from a plugin.
